# Python shows only errors when being its being saved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am new to Python. I configured my VS Code using `Python 3.8.8` inside an environment managed by miniconda.

When I now do right some piece of code, e.g.:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(test)
```

Only after saving the document and waiting a few seconds VS Code shows me there could be an error with the word test (undefined variable).
Why do this take so long and why it this only be analyzed when I save the file? Can I somewhere activate a live analyze function or similar?

Comment: What extensions do you have installed for Python? What's in your `settings.json` for the workspace?

Comment: Especially for python I do have the following: Indent-Rainbow, Jupyter, Kite Auto-complete, Pythoin Indent, Tabnine Autocomplete, Visual Studio IntelliCode. Unfortunatelly I do not see a `settings.json` in my working directory

Comment: This may help:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

Comment: set up a linter.  there are several options, most commonly used is pylint.  check this out(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)

Comment: Try installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance . Linters only work on saved files. You need an extension like this that works with a language server.

Comment: thank you I installed Pylance, may this solved the issue now I am getting warnings in real time